# How can I show the average rating in index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, my average rating is in the show page.

But how do I show this average rating in the index like besides each surf school's name? I'm having trouble with this because on index, we use @surf_school.each do |surf_schools|.

The code below is my code for showing the average rating in the show page.

surf_schools_controller.rb

```
class SurfSchoolsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    before_action :surf_school_find, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @surf_schools = SurfSchool.all
  end

  def new
    @surf_school = current_user.surf_schools.build
  end

  def create
    @surf_school = current_user.surf_schools.build(surf_school_params)
    if @surf_school.save
        redirect_to surf_schools_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    if @surf_school.surf_school_reviews.blank?
      @average_surf_school_review = 0
    else
      @average_surf_school_review = @surf_school.surf_school_reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @surf_school.update(surf_school_params)
        redirect_to surf_schools_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @surf_school.destroy
    redirect_to surf_schools_path
  end

  private

  def surf_school_params
    params.require(:surf_school).permit(:name, :country, :location, :phone, :email, :url)
  end

  def surf_school_find
    @surf_school = SurfSchool.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    unless @surf_school.user_id == current_user.id
      redirect_to surf_schools_path, notice: "Not authorized to perform this action."

      false
    end
  end

end
```

show.html.erb

```
<p><%= link_to "Back", surf_schools_path %></p>

</br>

<h5>Average Rating: </h5>
 <div class="average-surf_school_review-rating" data-score=<%= @average_surf_school_review %>></div>
    <%= @average_surf_school_review %> (
    <%= @surf_school.surf_school_reviews.count %>
    <% if @surf_school.surf_school_reviews.count <= 1 %>
        review
    <% else %>
        reviews
    <% end %>
    )

<p><%= link_to "Add Review", new_surf_school_surf_school_review_path(@surf_school) %></p>

</br>

<p><%= render @surf_school.surf_school_reviews %></p>



<script>
    $('.surf_school_review-rating').raty({
        readOnly: true,
        score: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-score');
        },
        path: '/assets/'
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('.average-surf_school_review-rating').raty({
        readOnly: true,
        path: '/assets/',
        score: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-score')
        }
    });
</script>
```

and here's my index.html.erb

```
<% @surf_schools.each do |surf_school| %>
    <h2><%= surf_school.name %></h2>
    <p>Country: <%= surf_school.country_name %></p>
    <p>Location: <%= surf_school.location %></p>
    <p>Contact #: <%= surf_school.phone %></p>
    <p>E-mail: <%= surf_school.email %></p>
    <p>
        <%= link_to "Visit Site", surf_school.url, target: "_blank" %>
        <%= link_to "Read Reviews", surf_school %>
    </p>
    <% if current_user == surf_school.user %>
        <p>
            <%= link_to "Update", edit_surf_school_path(surf_school) %>
            <%= link_to "Unlist", surf_school, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your index page ....

```
<% @surf_schools.each_with_index do |surf_school, i| %>
  <div class="average-surf_school_review-rating-<%= i+1 %>" data-score="<%= surf_school.surf_school_reviews.average(:rating).round(2) %>"></div>
<% end %>

<%= hidden_field_tag 'surf_schools', @surf_schools.count %>

<script>    
    if($('#surf_schools').val() > 0){
      for (i = 1; i <= $('#surf_schools').val(); i++) {
        $('.average-surf_school_review-rating-'+i).raty({
          readOnly: true,
          path: '/assets/',
          score: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-score')
          }      
        });
      };
    }
</script>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yeah it works thanks. But one more thing I hope you don't mind, can you also show me how to show the integer value of the average rating and the # of ratings just like what I did in the show page? Basically, the index page will look like this: Surf School Name ****(this is a star) 4.0(this is the integer value of 4 stars as avg. rating) (based on 35 reviews). I already did this in show page but I don't know how to do it in index. Thanks!

Comment: I also discovered that when I create a new surf school which obviously has no reviews yet, it gives an error something like reviews.count is nil!